# javascript and php not quite working

Tags: php, javascript

You can look at the application here: [application](http://jsfiddle.net/YYMJS/6/)

I know the code doesn't work in jsfiddle but I have included my code in the jsfiddle so that you can see the whole code and the way it is laid out.  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YYMJS/6/)

Now if textbox is empty, it displays "false" in alert and displays a message which is fine.

The problem though is this:

If I type the correct or incorrect room number value in the textbox, it always states it is "false" and does not come with a javascript message.

What should happen is if textbox value matches database, then it should alert "true" and display a javascript message "room is Valid", if textbox value doesn't match database then it should alert "False" and display a javascript message "room is Invalid" How can I achieve this?

You can test the application, enter in these figures in the textbox if you wish for testing:

Valid room number CW5/10 , Invalid room number CN2/10.

Below is where error occurs:

```
 var js_var = [];
<?php while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($roomquery)){ ?>
js_var.push(<?php $data['roomChosen']; ?>);
<?php }?>
```

Jsfiddle application url updated above

Comment: This question is difficult to understand, and thus difficult to answer. The clearer your question, the more likely it is that you'll receive good answers.

Comment: js_var.push(<?php echo $data['roomChosen']; ?>); I think you're lacking the echo.

Comment: Still displays error, I am also having error on validation not defined everytime I click on "Prepare Questions" button. Please help, I have really been struggling on this for ages, I am really desperate for help

Answer (score 2):

I think you are lacking **echo**:

```
<script>
  var js_var = [];
  <?php while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($roomquery)){ ?>
  js_var.push(<?php echo $data['roomnumber']; ?>);
  <?php }?>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use it as

```
<script>
var js_var = [];
<?php while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($roomquery)){ ?>
js_var.push(<?php echo $data['roomnumber']; ?>);
<?php }?>

function checkroomnumber(){
 var roomnumber = document.getElementById("roomnumber").value;
 for (i = 0 ; i<js_var.length; i++){
   if (js_var[i]==roomnumber){
     alert("room is correct");
     return true;
   }
 }
 alert("room is incorrect");
 return false;
}
</script>

<input type="textbox" name="roomnumber" id="roomnumber" />
<input type="button" name="checkroom" value="checkroom" onclick= "checkroomnumber();" />
```

Comment: I am getting an error on a particular code stating invalid regular exression flag w, roomquery is undefined, I have posted the code I am getting an error in on bottom of my question, I have updated jsfiddle so you can see the current code